# SQL to return one row from many

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data

| PersonId | City | Type | UpdateDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Boston | P | 01/01/2021 |
| 123 | Boston | M | 02/01/2021 |
| 130 | Detroit | P | 01/01/2021 |
| 130 | Detroit | M | 03/01/2021 |
| 140 | Dallas | M | 02/01/2021 |
| 140 | Dallas | M | 03/01/2021 |

I want a query that returns one row per PersonId.  If the Type is "P" return that row otherwise return the row with the minimum UpdateDate.  So the query would return:

| PersonId | City | Type | UpdateDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Boston | P | 01/01/2021 |
| 130 | Detroit | P | 01/01/2021 |
| 140 | Dallas | M | 02/01/2021 |

In the past I would write a query like

```
select * from person, address
where person.PersonId = address.PersonId
group by PersonId
having (Type = 'P') or (UpdateDate = min(UpdateDate))
```

but this is not allowed anymore.

What should my SQL query be in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you want the most recent address per person.  If so, `outer apply` is very well suited to this problem:

```
select p.* a.*
from person p outer apply
     (select top (1) a.*
      from address a
      where a.PersonId = p.PersonId
      order by (case when a.type = 'P' then 1 else 2 end),
               a.updatedate desc
     ) a;
```

No aggregation is called for.